# Moving a wordpress blog to a new host with the same domain name

Tags: wordpress, new-operator, transfer, host

I have just signed up to a new webhost with the same main domain name as my previous host. I downloaded the whole site via FTP and also exported the database in phpMyAdmin.

After changing the wp-config.php file so that the database name, username and password matched the details for my new host, I uploaded the files to the public_html folder (same directory as on the old host) and also imported the database.

Whilst I can log in, nothing has really saved. I had to set the theme again, none of the posts display etc. The information is all in the database, so I don't understand what has gone wrong.

What do you think the problem could be?

Comment: You've transferred the DNS so it points at the new server? Otherwise you'd be viewing the site on the old server...

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you got all the files. Important files that could be missing are .htacces files: they are 'hidden' (that's what the `.` kinda says, and some FTP programs just ignore them
2. Check if you are actually working on the correct host. If the DNS isn't pointing correctly (it can differ between sessions if it isn't propagated!), you're messing with 2 servers :)

Comment: I've just tried deleting all the files and uploading using Transmit instead of FireFTP this time. I get an error message saying 'Error -111: Could not bind the data socket' for a few files but I can't find anything about this. Also, it appears that not everything is copying over within subfolders, even though there is no message to tell me. The DNS is fine, that's sorted with Godaddy and everything is pointing towards the new host.

Comment: Did you set your FTP in "passive" mode? That helps most of the time

Comment: Yep, Transmit was in passive mode. I deleted everything and uploaded it with yet another FTP client. This time the page loads with the theme that I set, however it's the bare theme without any of my modifications such as header logo, page navigation or posts. So the backend is there, all the plugins etc, it just seems that none of my settings or content is saved.

Comment: The missing of he theme could be missing settings. You sure that the database backup went ok? If the databse is messed up, settings, posts etc might not work...

Comment: Well looking at it in phpMyAdmin everything is okay. I still have access to my old host for another 3 days, if you can suggest anything then I could change the nameservers back to the old hosting?

Comment: I'm sorry, all out of clues :(

Answer (score 0):

The way you described, everything should work. Also make sure you clear your cache and cookies so that the new server is recognized with your install. Also make sure that your URL settings have not changed in the general tab in the admin side.